# Django: model.ForeignKey referring to field type

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I try to build a model, e.g. `Userprofile`, in which fields will be chosen in the admin panel.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    regfield = models.ForeignKey(Regfields)
```

This model refers to a second  model `Regfields`:

```
class Regfields(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256, unique=True, blank=False)
    field_type = models.ForeignKey(FOREIGNKEY_TO_DATATYPES)
```

I want to choose the Fieldname and the Fieldtype (e.g. Char_field ...) to use this in a second model `Userprofile`, to refer to the field names and field types in the `Regfields` model. What is the best approach to realize this?

Edit:

I don't seek to have a kind of dynamic database for the user profile. I think I could achive something like this by using a "static" choice list, e.g.:

```
FIELD_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (BigIntegerField,'Long Int'),
    (BooleanField,'Boolean'),
    (CharField,'Char'),
    ...
    )
field_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=FIELD_TYPE_CHOICES, default=CharField)
```

However, this way I can have the required registration fields to be choosen from a given set, but I only get the fieldtypes as strings, which in turn might lead to complicated data validation.

Example of what i try to achive:
In the admin panel I want the admin to have they choice what kind of data is required (additionally to username and password) at the registration page. The admin might like to ask for (username, password and email) but might also ask for (username, password, email, first_name, last_name, company, department)

Comment: Because the default django model fields have to be stored in the database structure, you can't simply have dynamic field types if that is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you provide one or two concrete examples of user profiles that you wish to create this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing users to customize forms via forms is not that simple, and will probably drag you into more non standard problems... How about trying out a ready made django package that helps building forms?

https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/form-builder/

Comment: I guess django-fobi seems to have the best tradeoff regarding flexibility and complexity. Thanks!